# how to trim text and remove extra information in python

Tags: python

Hey Guys i am trying to scrape some data from ebay everything is working fine but the problem is i want to remove the extra text from data for example i am getting

> $10.99 to $13.69

and i only want to get

> $13.69

this is the html code

```
<span class="s-item__price">
"$10.99"
<span class="DEFAULT"> to </span>
"$13.69"</span>
```

This is the python code i am using

```
find(class_='s-item__price').text
```

Comment: `"$10.99 to $13.69".split(" to ")[-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
s = '$10.99 to $13.69'
val  = s[s.rfind('$'):]
print(val)
```

output

```
$13.69
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.stripped_strings` property to get all text nodes under price span and take the last one.

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''
<span class="s-item__price">
    "$10.99"
    <span class="DEFAULT"> to </span>
    "$13.69"
</span>
''')

price_el = soup.select_one('.s-item__price')
strings = [*price_el.stripped_strings]
print(strings[-1])
```

output:

```
$13.69
```

Answer (score 0):

You may catch every price by this:

```
import re

def findAllPrices(content):
    return re.findall(r'\$\d+\.\d+',content)
```

```
findAllPrices("""<span class="s-item__price">
"$10.99"
<span class="DEFAULT"> to </span>
"$13.69"</span>""")[-1]
```

```
'$13.69'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have string so you can use string's functions to get it

```
result = "$10.99 to $13.69".split(" to ")[-1]

print(result)
```

Or you can find `class=DEFAULT` and get `next_sibling`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

data ='''<span class="s-item__price">
"$10.99"
<span class="DEFAULT"> to </span>
"$13.69"</span>'''

soup = BS(data, 'html.parser')

item = soup.find('span', class_="DEFAULT")
result = item.next_sibling

result = result.strip()

print(result)
```